# extra bold font showing as regular bold in Chrome

Tags: css, sass, webfonts

I'm trying to use this font, Open Sans Extra-Bold:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans

For some reason I can't get it to show.

Any help?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0hhbgyrd/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800');
div {
  font-size: 90px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.normal {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.extra-bold {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">
  Blog
</div>

<div class="bold">
  Blog
</div>

<div class="extra-bold">
  Blog
</div>
```

EDIT: Seems this works correctly in Firefox, but not in Chrome?

Chrome:

[image: How it looks in Chrome:]

Firefox:

[image: How it looks in Firefox:]

Comment: Seems to work correctly in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Comment: This is work correct in Chrome

Comment: Seems to be working fine on Chrome 54.

Comment: Try to clear your cache and reload. I think this will work.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 55, 700 & 800 are showing the same for me.

Comment: This works fine in Firefox and Chrome 55.0.x version. this could be a cache issue. try incognito mode and check once.

Comment: I'm also using Chrome 55, this issue might be local (cache?).

Comment: Tried ctrl + F5, tried with and without chache killer addon, tried in incognito mode, keep getting the same bad result.

Comment: Actually the 3rd version is even slightly smaller?

Comment: can you try using <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet"> instead of @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800');

Comment: Nothing changes when using the link href instead of the import. But then again, nothing changes either when I just remove them both ...

Answer (score 0):

Fix the incorrect @import code provided by Google Fonts.

The import code they provide is causing problems for me as well, and it did not have the ' -marks before they updated the whole Google Fonts -page, so they kind of broke the code in the progress of their update.

I sent out a hotfix request few months back when they did not have the code wrapped inside (), which of course didn't work either. They fixed it but left the ' -marks in, so it works for some but certainly not for all.

So remove those ' -marks and it should work just fine:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800);
```

instead of

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800');
```

I also recommend using the correct `font-family` markup:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you try to refresh the page with Ctrl + F5 after you changed this?

Comment: Added an additional fix (as an edit) that makes your `font-family` attribute more correct. The newest version of Chrome seems to be catching up on these small errors more than the previous versions.

Comment: Yeah noticed that too. Changed both the import and font-family, still getting the wrong result after Ctrl F5

Comment: Now that is weird. I'm also using the newest version of Google Chrome and for me it works with these fixes. Are you sure you're not overriding any of these CSS-stylings later on in your project?